# I have install nodejs but version is old

Tags: node.js

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
node-01@node01-desktop ~ $ node -v
v0.10.37
node-01@node01-desktop ~ $ npm -v
1.4.28

Comment: You can use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install the version you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) script to install and manage multiple versions of nodejs.

First, you need to install it on your system.

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

This will download and install the script. Once the installation is over, do a

```
nvm ls-remote
```

This will list all the version of nodejs that is available for use.

```
...
    v8.8.1
    v8.9.0   (LTS: Carbon)
    v8.9.1   (LTS: Carbon)
    v8.9.2   (LTS: Carbon)
    v8.9.3   (LTS: Carbon)
    v8.9.4   (Latest LTS: Carbon)
    v9.0.0
    v9.1.0
    v9.2.0
    v9.2.1
    v9.3.0
    v9.4.0
...
```

It is recommended to use the recent LTS, so we need to use `v8.9.4 (Latest LTS: Carbon)`.

```
nvm install v8.9.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the Node Version Manager.
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Just follow the instructions and there you go.
Now you can install node.js version 9.40 like:

```
nvm install 9.4.0
```

and it will be automatically set to standard.

Comment: No command 'nvm' found, did you mean:
 Command 'nvi' from package 'nvi' (universe)
 Command 'npm' from package 'npm' (universe)
 Command 'pvm' from package 'pvm' (universe)
 Command 'kvm' from package 'qemu-kvm' (main)
 Command 'nam' from package 'nam' (universe)
 Command 'vm' from package 'mgetty-voice' (universe)
 Command 'nm' from package 'binutils' (main)
 Command 'nm' from package 'binutils-multiarch' (main)
 Command 'n-m' from package 'python-networkmanager' (universe)
 Command 'lvm' from package 'lvm2' (main)
nvm: command not found

Comment: But the above problem trubling

Comment: If you have installed nvm from github with the install.sh, you have to run: 

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" 

in your command line plus: 

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm 

Just copy and paste